# Compiling C99 in cl compiler

Tags: c, visual-studio, c99, cl

I am using the microsoft cl compiler (the one that comes with Visual Studio 2013) and I am looking for a command to use when compiling to tell the compiler to support C99.. Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no switch it is always in the same mode. Actually Visual Studio 2013 does not properly support C99. The situation will become better in VS 2015 because the features are needed for C++11 compatibility. But there is no official C99 support.

There is a list of supported C99 library features in VS 2013: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx